# How to get back the full-width window drag area in Aurora 29?

Tags: firefox

Firefox 29.0a2 (Aurora, 2014-02-08) is out now and it has this terribly small drag area that in my case is almost fully covered with bookmarks and the green area is where you must precisely place the cursor to drag the window:

[image: 29.0a2 version of Aurora]

This is very bad. How do I return it to the previous state, where the menu options and bookmarks do not cover the top of the drag area and it's big and you don't need surgical precision to drag the window?

[image: older version of Aurora]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it wasn't hard. First you need to press the "sandwich" button on the right and select the bottom-left-most option.

[image]

Then in the newly opened tab, press another button, which is also bottom-left-most. ("title bar")

[image]

And here's everything back to normal:

[image]

Sorry for Russian UI, but the buttons should be there in any language.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to change the Firefox **browser.tabs.drawInTitlebar** setting to **false**.

1. Type `about:config` in your address bar.
2. Search for `browser.tabs.drawInTitlebar`.
3. Double-click to change value to **false**.